# Query not working in Ingres

Tags: sql, ingres

I've inherited some ingres database stuff. Never used ingres before. I found the following query to isolate distinct email address records.

```
select a.reg_uid as id, a.firstname, a.lastname, a.postzip_code, a.suburb, a.city, a.state, a.email, a.country 
from register a
inner join 
(
 select distinct email, min(reg_uid) as id from register 
  group by email 
) as b
on a.email = b.email 
and a.id = b.id
```

However, when I plug this into ingres, I get the error

```
"Table 'select' does not exist or is not owned by you."
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hopefully it isn't something crazy like spaces and line returns ie having to put `join (select ...) as b` on one line. Trying using the old syntax `from register a, (select ...) b where a.email = b.email and a.id = b.id`

Comment: What version of Ingres are you using? Have you tried the using Terminal Monitor to test your query?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ingres 10S (10.1) then you can use common table expressions (CTEs) as follows:

```
with b(email,id) as
(
 select distinct email, min(reg_uid) as id from register 
  group by email 
)
select a.reg_uid as id, a.firstname, a.lastname, a.postzip_code, a.suburb, a.city, a.state, a.email, a.country 
from register a
inner join b
on a.email = b.email 
and a.id = b.id
```

For earlier versions you could either create a view for b (a CTE is in effect an inline view) or re-write it as

```
select a.reg_uid as id, a.firstname, a.lastname, a.postzip_code, a.suburb, a.city, a.state, a.email, a.country 
from register a
where a.id = (
 select min(reg_uid) as id from register b
 where b.email=a.email
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your exact statement successfully on Ingres 9:

```
create table register ( id char(10), reg_uid char(10), firstname char(10), lastname char(10), postzip_code char(10), suburb char(10), city char(10), state char(10), email char(10), country char(10) )

select a.reg_uid as id, a.firstname, a.lastname, a.postzip_code, a.suburb, a.city, a.state, a.email, a.country 
from register a
inner join 
(
 select distinct email, min(reg_uid) as id 
 from register 
  group by email 
) as b
on a.email = b.email 
and a.id = b.id
```